# Distinct rows from a list of dictionaries based on values

Tags: python

I have this sample input below **sampleInputDbData**

```
def sampleInputDbData( self ):
    return \
    [
        {'FundCode': 300, 'FundName': 'First Fund', 'ProdStartDate': dt(2016,7,3,4,5,6), 'ProdEndDate': dt(2016,8,3,4,5,6), 'FundFee': 100},
        {'FundCode': 300, 'FundName': 'First Fund', 'ProdStartDate': dt(2016,8,3,4,5,6), 'ProdEndDate': dt(2016,8,3,6,5,6), 'FundFee': 101 },
        {'FundCode': 300, 'FundName': 'First Fund', 'ProdStartDate': dt(2016,8,3,6,5,6), 'ProdEndDate': dt(2016,8,15,6,5,6), 'FundFee': 102 },
        {'FundCode': 301, 'FundName': 'Second Fund', 'ProdStartDate': dt(2016,7,3,4,5,6), 'ProdEndDate': dt(2016,8,3,6,5,6), 'FundFee': 110},
        {'FundCode': 301, 'FundName': 'Second Fund', 'ProdStartDate': dt(2016,8,3,6,5,6), 'ProdEndDate':  dt(2016,8,15,6,5,6), 'FundFee': 111},
        {'FundCode': 302, 'FundName': 'Third Fund', 'ProdStartDate': dt(2016,8,3,6,5,6), 'ProdEndDate':  dt(2016,8,15,6,5,6), 'FundFee': 120},
    ]
```

What I want is this **sampleOutputDbData** as output

```
def sampleOutputDbData( self ):
    return \
    [
        {'FundCode': 300, 'FundName': 'First Fund', 'ProdStartDate': dt(2016,8,3,6,5,6), 'ProdEndDate': dt(2016,8,15,6,5,6), 'FundFee': 102 },
        {'FundCode': 301, 'FundName': 'Second Fund', 'ProdStartDate': dt(2016,8,3,6,5,6), 'ProdEndDate':  dt(2016,8,15,6,5,6), 'FundFee': 111},
        {'FundCode': 302, 'FundName': 'Third Fund', 'ProdStartDate': dt(2016,8,3,6,5,6), 'ProdEndDate':  dt(2016,8,15,6,5,6), 'FundFee': 120},
    ]
```

The decision factor is basically: Get all unique **FundCode** based on max value of the key **ProdEndDate**. dt is type datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

code_dict = defaultdict(list)
for d in sampleInputDbData:
    code_dict[d["FundCode"]].append(d)

output_data = [max(d, key=itemgetter("ProdEndDate")) for d in code_dict.values()]
```

I first create a default dict for temporary sorting by `FundCode`. Each key will contain a list with all dicts with the same `FundCode`. Then, I'm taking the last `ProdEndDate` from each list.